# Connecting to a Docker Container from Windows 10 VirtualBox virtual machine

Tags: macos, docker, windows-10, virtualbox

How do I connect to a docker container running on a mac to a virtual box virtual machine running Windows 10? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks, Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Get started with multi-host networking:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/

Also check if this post helps:

- https://deis.com/blog/2016/connecting-docker-containers-2/